# MFP 7.0 Nov 2016 iFix Installation/Update Not Reflecting in MFP Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We just had installed the latest iFix (7.0.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201611140235) in our app server. Upon checking the version in the MFP Console, it still in the previous version. I've checked the directory /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer, and found that the .war files not been updated. I've check the installation history and it shows that I successfully installed/updated it. I also noticed that the file worklight-jee-library.jar still in the previous version.

How should I refresh the files? Looks like the installation is not updating the .war files and libraries.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: In addition to the above, do we need to uninstall the first installation before installing the interim fix?

Comment: By installing iFix, did you only install it using Installation manager? If so , that is not sufficient. You need to use server configuration tool or ANT scripts to update the runtime as well.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v710/mfpf_apply_server_v71_fixpack.pdf

Comment: Hi, yes, I only install using Installation Manager in Linux. The problem is, when I checked the WAR and JAR files of the interim fix in product_install_dir/
WorklightServer folder after installation, it still contains the old files. My method is manually apply the fix pack as per page 17 in the manual you provided on this link http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v710/mfpf_apply_server_v71_fixpack.pdf. What else should I check? Thanks

Comment: Did Installation manager throw an error while updating? One other approach you could try ( just to check), is to install the fixpack to a new location and not update the existing one. Check if this new directory contains updates war and jar files

Comment: There is no error thrown during/after installation, it says, successfully updated MobileFirst Server. We will try to install in another server and see if it will contain the new war and jar files. Thanks

Comment: Any updates to this question?

Comment: Hi Idan. What we did is to manually copy the WAR and JAR files to Tomcat folders (/webapps and/ lib). It is now showing the correct version in the console. We recompile the app using this iFix version (IF201611140235), and deploy the new app WAR file to the server.

However, the issues we are fixing were not fix (related to Android devices, due to recent Chrome update). Scrolling lag issue is still happening. I am having same issue with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331138/dojo-mobile-list-scrolling-lag-issue-on-samsung-device-android-6-0-1

Comment: I have replied to said question. Unfortunately that is out of the mfp framework control. Can you please write the above as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> What we did is to manually copy the WAR and JAR files to Tomcat folders (/webapps and/ lib). It is now showing the correct version in the console. We recompile the app using this iFix version (IF201611140235), and deploy the new app WAR file to the server.